# Fast way to find index of max/min element in Nth column of matrix

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, indexof

I am trying to get the index of the maximum and minimum element of a specific column in the matrix. Now I am doing as follows using ES6 and Spread syntax:

```js
a = [
  [22,23],
  [74,1],
  [21,33],
  [32,84],
  [11,31],
  [1,49],
  [7,8],
  [11,11],
  [99,68],
  [52,20]
];

const minValue = (arr, n) => Math.min(...arr.map(x => x[n])); //n - column index
const maxValue = (arr, n) => Math.max(...arr.map(x => x[n]));

const minValueIndex = (arr, n) => arr.map(x => x[n]).indexOf(minValue(arr, n));
const maxValueIndex = (arr, n) => arr.map(x => x[n]).indexOf(maxValue(arr, n));

console.log(minValue(a, 0));
console.log(maxValue(a, 0));

console.log(minValueIndex(a, 0));
console.log(maxValueIndex(a, 0));
```

But at the same time too many comparisons are made, I do not think that this is the best way to complete this task. I would be glad to see faster implementations using the ES6 standard or without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to loop over the array and store the min/max values in a temporary variable.

```js
function minMax (arr, n) {
    let min=Infinity, max=0;
    for (const _arr of arr) {
        const x = _arr[n];
        if (x < min) min = x;
        if (x > max) max = x;
    }
    return [min, max];
}

function minMaxIndex (arr, n) {
    let min=Infinity, max=0, minIndex, maxIndex;
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const x = arr[i][n];
        if (x < min) {
          min = x;
          minIndex = i;
        }
        if (x > max) {
          max = x;
          maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return [minIndex, maxIndex];
}

console.log (minMax(a, 0))
console.log (minMaxIndex(a, 0))
```

```html
<script>
a = [
  [22,23],
  [74,1],
  [21,33],
  [32,84],
  [11,31],
  [1,49],
  [7,8],
  [11,11],
  [99,68],
  [52,20]
];
</script>
```

Comment: In the index search function, it is probably necessary to assign the index value of the current max/min to another variable.It turns out that you are comparing the value with the index and the result, respectively, is incorrect

Comment: @NikitaKobtsev Woopsie! You're right of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you, now it looks like the fastest solution presented here, albeit in a functional style. But is it possible to reduce this code using ES6 or even turn it into one-liner, while maintaining the same performance?

Comment: Is this linear versus cubic complexity in my solution, right?)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there and you are just concern about the performance right? So for improving the performance of your program, you can use a nice technique called [`Memoization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

> Memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up
>   computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls
>   and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again

```js
const arr = [[22,23], [74,1], [21,33], [32,84], [11,31], [1,49], [7,8], [11,11], [99,68], [52,20]];

/**
* Here I create the momoized function which cache the
* column and if we want to get the same column then it
* simply return the previously cached column array
* otherwise, it get the column and cache it for future
* and return it.
*/
const memoized = () => {
 const cache = {};

 return (arr, index) => {
     if (index in cache) {
         return cache[index];
     } else {
  const col = arr.map(item => (item[index]));
  cache[index] = col;
  return col;
     }
 }
}

/**
* As memoized is a higher order function so it returns
* another function which will be executed by calling
* this getColumn function reference.
*/
const getColumn = memoized();

const getMinValue = (arr, col) => Math.min(...getColumn(arr, col));
const getMaxValue = (arr, col) => Math.max(...getColumn(arr, col));

const minValueIndex = (arr, col) => getColumn(arr, col).indexOf(getMinValue(arr, col));
const maxValueIndex = (arr, col) => getColumn(arr, col).indexOf(getMaxValue(arr, col));

console.log('minValue: ', getMinValue(arr, 0)); // Calculated
console.log('maxValue: ',getMaxValue(arr, 0)); // Cached

console.log('minValueIndex: ', minValueIndex(arr, 0)); // Cached
console.log('maxValueIndex: ', maxValueIndex(arr, 0)); // Cached
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: The task was to find the minimum / maximum in a certain column, and not among all elements

Comment: Okay! then your output misleading me. Could you please tell me what is the ```n``` is? the index number?

Comment: I get it. Sorry it's by bad.

Comment: This is just my bad. I indicated in the topic, but in the task itself I wrote the description incorrectly, corrected and added a comment about what `n` is

Comment: Extracting from cache vs each time searching will undoubtedly work faster with reusing of an unmodified matrix. But still, the task was to speed up the index search operation itself

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by index search operation.

Comment: Find the first occurrence of an element whose value for a particular column is minimum or maximum among all other values of this column. A problem that native methods do not solve, respectively, there can be many solutions. I decided using mainly ES6 syntax and it is easy to calculate that the Spread operator + Math.min()/max() + indexOf() give us `O(n*n*n)`(cubic) complexity. Correct me if I'm wrong. Obviously, this can be solved using a much smaller number of operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212090/discussion-between-sajeeb-ahamed-and-nikita-kobtsev).

Answer (score 1):

> Will this help?

```
let a = [
    [22, 23],
    [74, 1],
    [21, 33],
    [32, 84],
    [11, 31],
    [1, 49],
    [7, 8],
    [11, 11],
    [99, 68],
    [52, 20]
];
let max = 0,
    min = 0,
    minIndex = 0,
    maxIndex = 0;

const findValue = (array, col) => {
    array.map((matrix) => {
        (matrix[col] > max) ? max = matrix[col]: null;
        (min == 0) ? min = max: null;
        (matrix[col] < min) ? min = matrix[col]: null;
    })
}
const findIndex = (array, col, min, max) => {
    minIndex = array.map(data => data[col]).indexOf(min);
    maxIndex = array.map(data => data[col]).indexOf(max);
}

findValue(a, 0)
findIndex(a, 0, min, max);
console.log(min, max, minIndex, maxIndex);
```

Comment: It seems like a very good compromise between performance and brevity. Quadratic versus Cubic difficulty in my version. Thank you